# Twisted `callInThread` is blocking

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, asynchronous, twisted

I have a Twisted based program that I have simplified in the following excerpt:

```
    class PacketSender(object):

        def __init__(self, protocol_instance):
             self._stop = False
             self._protocol = protocol_instance

        def send(self, pkti):
            try:
                pkti1 = gen_packets.next()
                reactor.callInThread(self.write_packet, pkti)
            except StopIteration:
                self._stop = True

            do_some_stuff()

            if not self._stop:
                reactor.callLater(pkti.iat, self.send, pkti1)

        def write_packet(self, pkt):
            self.protocol.transport.write(pkt)
    ...
reactor.run()
```

Summarizing a lot, the `write_packet` method will call the `transport.write` method of a certain protocol instance I have passed to the constructor class `A`. Note this is a recursive implementation where The method `send` calls itself to get the following packet to send over the protocol. The problem is that when it calls `send` delayed `pkt.iat` seconds, the execution of send will die at that `callInThread` call, which **is supposed to spawn a new thread and continue with the execution of `do_some_stuff`**, right?? All this code is actually running in another twisted thread, meaning that at some point we are calling from outside `callInThread(packet_sender.send, pkt_0)`.

Do you have any clues about what might be happening? Is there something I'm missing about how Twisted threads work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.protocol.transport.write` is a method on an object in the reactor. You're not allowed to call this method in a non-reactor thread; the behavior is undefined. Blocking is one potential result of doing undefined things.  You also aren't allowed to have more than one reactor thread in a process.

[The twisted documentation on threading](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.1.0/core/howto/threading.html#running-code-in-a-thread-safe-manner) covers this; perhaps you should review it.  You almost certainly do not need to use threads at all for what you're trying to do (`transport.write` is *already* non-blocking so trying to do it in a thread would not help anyway); if you need threads for some reason not shown here perhaps you should ask a more specific question about how to avoid them for that task.

Comment: I couldn't find the definition of reactor and non-reactor threads in the documentation. Just to see if I understood correctly, does that mean that `reactor.callInThread()` will spawn a reactor thread (where the reactor is `reactor`)? Thank you